# code to add numbers in multiple files

Tags: perl, shell

I have multiple files which has below two entries:

```
$ cat file_01
Total capacity                   3.4 TB
Capacity used                    825.8 GB
```

Output of file is two rows. First row has Total Capacity and second row is Capacity used.

This is output for one server, I want it for my rest of server to be consolidated.

I want to create a simple script which will add all the Total capacity and all the Capacity used from multiple files and give one consolidated output. Shell or perl is what I am looking.

Any direction to this, would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are the sizes always in terabytes (or Tebibytes, TiB), or can they be in GiB, MiB, KiB too, or instead?  Indeed, are the sizes decimal-based or binary-based?

Comment: Some values are in TB and some in GB. I want conversion to be all in TB

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1TB = 1000GB:

```
cat file* |  perl -ne '
   /.* (\d+.\d+) ([TG])B .* (\d+.\d+) ([TG])B/;
   $x+=$1*($2==T?1000:1);
   $y+=$3*($4==T?1000:1);
   END{print "$x GB, $y GB\n"}'
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler just in case this is part of a pipeline and is being created dynamically.

Comment: @maneeshshetty are there two lines per file or one? are there tabs separating or spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all files report in TB (untested)

```
perl -lane '
    $total += $F[2]; $used += $F[6]; 
    END {print "total: $total; used: $used"}
' file*
```

If you have differing units, consider using something like [Math::Units](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aUnits) to convert, for instance, between TB and GB.

Answer (score 0):

Below should do the trick:

```
awk '{ if ($4 == "GB") $3/=1000; s[FNR] += $3 } END { print "total: "s[1]" TB\nused:  "s[2]" TB" }' file_*
```

FNR - row number in file

Answer (score 0):

## read and load a hash table for each type GB ,TB , etc ..

```
cat file? | perl -ne '
chomp;
@x = split(/\s+/,$_);
$total{$x[-1]} += $x[-2];
while(<>){
  chomp;
  @x = split(/\s+/,$_);
  $total{$x[-1]} += $x[-2];
};
for $m1 ( keys %total ) {
  print "$m1 , $total{$m1}\n";
};
'
```